# Laravel : Upload 64base image instead of normal

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, intervention

I have an application using **React** and **Laravel** where I'm uploading images.
I'm using [Laravel Image Intervention package](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction).

When testing my API, the upload for a normal image works perfectly.

Using **React**, the user can select an image from his pc and crop it, then he sees the preview as a **generated cropped 64base image**.

**I would want to upload the generated 64base image to my database instead of a normal one, how to do so ?**

`Fileupload controller`

```
 public function Store(Request $request)
    {
 $this->validate($request, [
 'filename' => 'image|required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'
 ]);
 $originalImage= $request->file('filename');
 $thumbnailImage = Image::make($originalImage);
 
 // Define upload path
 $originalPath = public_path('/images/');
 
 // Save Orginal Image
 $thumbnailImage->save($originalPath.time().$originalImage->getClientOriginalName());
 
 // Save In Database
 $imagemodel= new Photo();
 $imagemodel->photo_name=time().$originalImage->getClientOriginalName();
 $imagemodel->save();
 
 return back()->with('success', 'Image Upload successful');
 
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend not to do so. 1. it would take much longer to upload and would possible time out on larger files, 2. you would benefit from uploading the original image and crop (what the user selected) on server side - in that case it would be passible to crop the original image later again.

Comment: @Gordon Freeman I see. But I actually had an idea. Why don't I pass directly the 64base code into the database and load it directly ?

Comment: It depends on your database and your app in general. I would not store base64 images in database, for multiple reasons: 1. they would be much slower delivered, 2. the database would take much more space than necessary, 3. there would be much more load on the database (is expensive)

Comment: @Gordon Freeman Very interesting points you got. But for now it's not possible for the user to upload THEN crop the image. So I guess I'm going with the uploading directly the 64base code to the server because 1.I'm uploading small avatar files 2. I'm putting a restriction of the upload size in the front end. So I think this is a good solution, what do you think ?

Comment: Should work. We are using cropperjs a lot. The way we solved it for the upload, we pass the x, y, width, height parameters alongside with the uploaded file to the server. Then save the path to the image and the said parameters and handle all the cropping with InterventionImage. Works just fine.

Comment: @Gordon Freeman I see. Like a delayed processing of the image by getting the parameters. That's very good. Anyway I did a small test of saving the cropped image directly into my pc and reading the 64basecode in the web, the difference at max was 5kb-7kb. I guess it should be alright. Thank you very much for the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work

```php
$folderPath = "images/";

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->file('file'));
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
$file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '. '.$image_type;

// file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
Storage::put($file, $image_base64);
```

Possible alternative:

```php
$image =  Image::make(base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $request->file('file'))))->stream();
Storage::put($file, $image, 'public');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But isn't it the same as passing the base64 to the database ? I see that your code take the image and convert it. I might be wrong.

Comment: No. Storage puts it to your filesystem (or a cloud). So your webserver (Apache/Nginx) will be responsible for it

Comment: I see. So it takes the 64image and actually store it as a normal one.

Comment: Yes. That is the idea. I did not test this code, but i think it should work. Maybe put a `file_get_contents` around `$request->file('file')`

Comment: I will see if I can fit it in my code later. But I will definitely use your solution. Thank you so much.